# Terminal USB Memory Management

Tags: command-line, usb, mount

due to a problem that I had with my ubuntu 14.04 , I am forced to enter the terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F1 logon , and I require to know how to put on a USB stick and pass data (files, etc ) if I could help showing me the steps I should follow once the terminal would greatly appreciate encerio ( in case I add that I am not an expert on linux but rather to use the terminal , always do superuser mode because the permissions that sometimes I require )

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution , once set the device to track your position `blkid` that returned me to `/dev/sdb5` , then mount it in the directory with a directory called usbMemory did so :

```
# create the directory
mkdir /home/mail/usbMemory/
# the mount
mount -t vfat  -o rw  /dev/sdb5/     home/nico/ usbMemory
```

and then I just go there copying folders.

Comment: indeed! it worked